# Interval between two dates is not integer in PHP

Tags: php, date, intervals, mktime

I'm using this to echo interval number of days between two dates, but the second line echoes a float number.

```
echo (mktime(0,0,0,10,27,2013)-mktime(0,0,0,8,18,2013))/(3600*24).'<br>';
echo (mktime(0,0,0,10,28,2013)-mktime(0,0,0,8,18,2013))/(3600*24).'<br>';
```

Result:

```
70
71.041666666667
```

Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why but seems like it's about timezone setting, I changed to
date.timezone = Asia/Shanghai in php.ini and now am getting integer (correct) result

Comment: @user1466527 It's not about it, read my answer.

Comment: @Glavić I don't think so. Check Europe/Moscow which is not using DST (as you can see on your map). It's all about numbers. When you change timezone, result from `mktime` changes to number divisible or not by 3600*24.

Comment: @Glavić I read again question and our answers and I think we're both right. You're right about why `mktime` result changes, I'm right about why result from this expression is float.

Comment: @Glavić Using `Europe/Moscow` for `mktime(0,0,0,10,28,2013)-mktime(0,0,0,8,18,2013);` will return float. But for `mktime(0,0,0,10,27,2013)-mktime(0,0,0,8,18,2013);` will return int. Check it :)

Comment: @ElonThan: so? The OP is asking: `Result: 70 & 71.041666666667. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!` And your answer is: `first is returning int, second float`?

Comment: @Glavić I also answered why second value is float. You just told him how to change it by changing timezone, which isn't full answer.

Comment: @ElonThan: hehe. We can go on and on, **but what OP's is trying to find out is, why is he getting float when he should be getting integer**. OP knows and sees that he is getting float. He need solution for not getting float at all, not how to round or cast float when he gets it.

Comment: @ElonThan: and no, my answer is not to change timezone. He wrote that by him self in first comment. I answered **why** he is getting that kind of result. And for solution I advised to use DateTime class. It is a valid answer for this question, and no need for -1.

Answer (score -1):

Because when dividing in PHP, you'll always receive float.

To get int you have to round it or cast it.

```
 $int = (int) $float;
```

or

```
 $int = round($float, 0);
```

One exception is when both operands are integers (or strings that can be cast to integers) and they are divisible.

Answer (score -1):

> Result: 71.041666666667. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!

### ***ANSWER:*** You get that kind of the result because of the [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

> I changed to date.timezone = Asia/Shanghai in php.ini and now am getting integer (correct) result.

Because `Asia/Shanghai` timezone doesn't use DST. For example try timezone `Europe/Berlin` (who uses DST), and you will see that you are having the same problem :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Shanghai');
echo (mktime(0,0,0,10,28,2013)-mktime(0,0,0,8,18,2013))/(3600*24); # 71

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
echo (mktime(0,0,0,10,28,2013)-mktime(0,0,0,8,18,2013))/(3600*24); # 71.041666666667
```

[image]

<sup>DST is used [blue] | DST is no longer used [orange] | DST has never been used [red]</sup>

---

That's why I always suggest to use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) instead of *mktime()*, *strtotime()* and similar function. [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) handles leap years and time-zones correctly.

```
$f = new DateTime('2013-08-18');
$t = new DateTime('2013-10-28');
echo $f->diff($t)->days; # 71
```

Or one-liner (PHP >= 5.4) :

```
echo (new DateTime('2013-08-18'))->diff(new DateTime('2013-10-27'))->days; # 71
```

Comment: Downvoters: please let me know what I did wrong here. Thanks.